# Convert YYYY-MM-DD date (without time zone) to unix timestamp in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, date, timestamp, type-conversion

I've got a column of type `date` with the following value format: `YYYY-MM-DD` (eg. `2018-08-03`). I want to get the unix timestamp equivalent of the dates, but without the timezone.

F.e. the date `2018-08-03` should equal `1533254400` (as of calculated [here](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php)).

I've tried `to_timestamp(my_date_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` but it returns error `function to_timestamp(date, unknown) does not exist`. I've tried adding different variations of `::timestamp...` at the end of the function call, but to no avail.

Currently I do the timestamp conversion in the application layer, but I'd like to dedicate that job to the database.

Comment: to_timestamp does the opposite (Epoch to datetime/timestamp).

Answer (score 7):

Alright... after a change in my approach, I decided to try to "extract" data instead of convert. Turned out there's the oh-so convenient function `extract` in Postgres, which does exactly what I want.

`extract(EPOCH from my_date_column) as date_timestamp`

[Here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-extract/) is a more detailed explanation.

Comment: You can find all datetime related operators and functions of PostgreSQL at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html